# PhantomJS download using a javascript link

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping, phantomjs

I am attempting to scrape the below website:

http://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=8&season=2011&month=0&season1=2011&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&players=0

If you click the small button at the top-right of the table titled "export data", a javascript script runs and my browser downloads the file in .csv form.  I'd like to be able to write a PhantomJS script that can do this automatically.  Any ideas?

The above button is coded into HTML as such:

```
<a id="LB_cmdCSV" href="javascript:__doPostBack('LB$cmdCSV','')">Export Data</a></div>
```

I also found this function in the HTML source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

I'm very new to PhantomJS/Javascript and could use some pointers here. I think I've found all the info I need to do this automatically (correct me if I'm wrong), but just not sure where to start on coding it. Thanks for any help.

EDIT - This is what my script looks like right now:

```
var page = new WebPage();
url = 'http://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=8&season=2011&month=0&season1=2011&ind=0&team=0&rost=0& players=0';

page.open(encodeURI(url), function (status){
  if (status !== "success") {
    console.log("Unable to access website");
  } else {
      page.evaluate(function() {
        __doPostBack('LB$cmdCSV', '');
      });
    }
  phantom.exit(0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What have worked very well for me is simulating mouse clicks on the desired element.

```
page.evaluate(function () {
  var btn = document.getElementById('LB_cmdCSV')
  var ev = document.createEvent('MouseEvent')
  ev.initEvent('click', true, true)
  btn.dispatchEvent(ev)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just run the code, `__doPostBack('LeaderBoard1$cmdCSV','');`, within the context of the webpage?

Something like this:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
  __doPostBack('LeaderBoard1$cmdCSV','');
});
```

I haven't tested this code within PhantomJS, but theoretically it should work since running the __doPostBack method from Google Chrome's developer console worked. If in doubt about running JavaScript code in PhantomJS, Google Chrome's developer console is a great way to test out the code as it runs on WebKit like PhantomJS. I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the tips. I started testing stuff out in Chrome's developer console and I've got the javascript to work and the file downloads correctly.  However, when running the same code from the command line using phantomJS, nothing happens.  Could this be because I need to specify where to download the file(whereas Chrome settings always place it in /home/downloads/)?

Comment: Also added my current script to the OP

Comment: This method didn't work for me in casperJS.  Although I'm doing it on a different ASPX site.

Comment: I haven't used CasperJS so I can't be certain that this method would work from that context.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to specify where to download the file?

Answer (score -1):

It's an ASP powered website so this is going to be a tad trickier than most and you will have to use cURL commands to mimic POSTing the entire form viewstate & eventvalidation strings back to server. Probably just be easier just to lift the data straight out of the page you have.

Comment: Thanks for the response (although I'm a little confused). Previously, I'd just grab the data straight out of the webpage using BeautifulSoup and Python when there was only one page for the table. However the website changed their table to have multiple pages that are accessible by a javascript function. This function is once again __doPostBack and it's called as such: javascript:__doPostBack('LB$dg1$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$ctl05',''). Is there a way that I could scrape the info from the table, then change the page using this function? I could then just recurse until I have scraped every page.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Ruby on Rails and Watir Webdriver (https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver).

I have identified that the tool using the ASP.NET when using the "doPostBack" identical browser used by the User Agent defined by the customer. When using PhantomJS the user agent is identified as something "Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/534.34 PhantomJS/1.9.1".

Therefore it is necessary to change the user agent client before accessing the page. Rails and did something like:

```
HTTP_USER_AGENT    = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
HTTP_DRIVER        = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs, :desired_capabilities => Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.phantomjs(
  "phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent" => HTTP_USER_AGENT
)
...
browser = Watir::Browser.new HTTP_DRIVER, :http_client => client
```